# JPA Repository can't find value

Tags: jpa, crud, option-type

Entity ->

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
public class ConfirmationToken {
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "confirmation_token_sequence",
            sequenceName = "confirmation_token_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @Id @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "confirmation_token_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String token;




    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", nullable = false)
    private Account account;

    public ConfirmationToken(String token, Account account) {
        this.token = token;
        this.account = account;
    }
}
```

repository ->

```
    @Repository
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public interface ConfirmationTokenRepository extends 
           JpaRepository<ConfirmationToken, Long> {
    Optional<ConfirmationToken> findByToken(String token);
   }
```

service1 ->

```
    public Optional<ConfirmationToken> getToken(String token) {
        return confirmationTokenRepository.findByToken(token);
    }
```

service2 ->

```
    @Override
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService.getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("Token not found"));

        return "Token Verified";
    }
```

error ->
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Token not found

I checked token is in the database normally but repository still can't get the value in the database
I don't know what's causing this problem.

Comment: How are you checking this token is in the database, and how are you putting it there? You might also check the SQL statements being issued for your query, as it might not match what you are using to check that it exists - you might need to verify that you have an account as well, as I believe your model causes Hibernate to use an inner join to account when fetching ConfirmationToken.

Comment: I just found out there was no query created. thanks :)